# How do I get Windows back on my Dell Laptop after a secure wipe?

Tags: boot, laptop

I just did a secure wipe on my Dell G15 5511 laptop to get rid of a Linux Image on my laptop.  Unfortunately it cannot do an HTTPS boot to get a new windows OS.

In my BIOS Setup, I only have three Boot Sequences available inside my Boot Configuration. They are as follows (in order):

1. ONBOARD NIC (IPV4)
2. ONBOARD NIC (IPV6)
3. UEFI HTTPs Boot

All of them fail at trying to install an OS, regardless if I am connected to Ethernet or not.

What do I do from here to get Windows back on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On another PC download Windows through Media Creation Tool, when asked save it to an USB flash drive. Boot from that USB drive on your laptop and install Windows.